# Changing "In this Column" property of Custom Lookup field Programmatically

Tags: list, sharepoint-designer, column

I am creating a LookUp Column Programmatically for a custom list which is already there, and trying to change the property shown in attached picture using C#, but I couldn't figure out whats the name of the property or any code to change it.

If I know the name of the property, then I can use method

```
"SetCustomProperty(property name, value)"
```

I am using Moss for Dev.

Cheers
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [SPFieldLookup.LookupField Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookup.lookupfield.aspx).

However, this property is write-once. If you try to change it after it has been set, you will get an exception.